# Express cookie with redirect does not set cookie on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I have some code that sets a cookie on a response then redirects the response to another address. For some reason the cookie is not visible on the client when I do `document.cookie`. The strange thing is that I see in the chrome dev console that the response of the request that triggers the redirect has the cookie attached to it. Im using React on the client and Express Node.js on the backend.

Heres the express code, I've tried without `httpOnly` and `secure`. I've also tried just setting `httpOnly` to false. I've tried httpOnly with `secure` true and false.

```
res.cookie('session_token', results.session, { httpOnly: false, secure: true });
res.redirect(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL);
```

Comment: If it's `httpOnly` it can't be accessed with clientside javascript, so that has to be turned off. If it's `secure` it only works with SSL(https). Cookies are generally only available on the same domain, so you are of course redirecting to a page on the same domain. Also note that the cookie only lives for a session by default. You have read the documentation -> http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: The page is on a different domain, is there any way around this restriction?

Comment: If it's not your website, and you don't have control over it, then no, it would be a major security flaw if you could set cookies for other websites.

Comment: Both websites are mine

Comment: You still can't share cookies across different domains, but there are other ways to pass data, for instance a POST request, and then setting the cookie on the other domain etc.